# rails : type search with data address use elasticsearch chewy gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I use chewy gem elasticsearch .

I have LocationsIndex, mapping :

```
class LocationsIndex < Chewy::Index
  settings analysis: {
    analyzer: {
      folding: {
          tokenizer: "standard",
          filter:  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        },
      sorted: {
        tokenizer: 'keyword',
        filter: ['lowercase', 'asciifolding']
      }
    }
  }

  define_type Location do
    field :name, type: 'string', analyzer: 'standard' do
      field :folded, type: 'string', analyzer:   "folding"
    end
    field :address, type: 'string', analyzer: 'standard' do
      field :address, type: 'string', analyzer: 'folding'
    end
    field :locations, type: 'geo_point', value: ->{ {lat: lat, lon: lon} }
  end

end
```

when i query:

```
LocationsIndex::Location.query(
        multi_match: {
          query: keyword,
          fields: ["address", "address.folded" ,"name", "name.folded"]
        }
      )
```

data sample :

> {   "took" : 2,   "timed_out" : false,   "_shards" : {
>       "total" : 5,
>       "successful" : 5,
>       "failed" : 0   },   "hits" : {
>       "total" : 10,
>       "max_score" : 1.0,
>       "hits" : [ {
>         "_index" : "locations",
>         "_type" : "location",
>         "_id" : "131",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"name":"Việt Nam","address":"Việt Nam","locations":{"lat":16.9054,"lon":106.576}}
>       }, {
>         "_index" : "locations",
>         "_type" : "location",
>         "_id" : "136",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"name":"Quan truong Ngo Mon","address":"23/8, Thừa Thiên Huế, Việt Nam","locations":{"lat":16.4669,"lon":107.58}}
>       }, {
>         "_index" : "locations",
>         "_type" : "location",
>         "_id" : "132",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"name":"Thừa Thiên Huế","address":"Thừa Thiên Huế, Việt Nam","locations":{"lat":16.4674,"lon":107.591}}
>       }, {
>         "_index" : "locations",
>         "_type" : "location",
>         "_id" : "137",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"name":"Phu Van Lau","address":"23/8, Thừa Thiên Huế, Việt Nam","locations":{"lat":16.4655,"lon":107.581}}
>       }, {
>         "_index" : "locations",
>         "_type" : "location",
>         "_id" : "133",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"name":"Ha Noi","address":"Ha Noi, Việt Nam","locations":{"lat":16.4674,"lon":107.591}}
>       }, {
>         "_index" : "locations",
>         "_type" : "location",
>         "_id" : "138",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"name":"Cau gia Vien","address":"Le Duan, Thừa Thiên Huế, Việt Nam","locations":{"lat":16.4601,"lon":107.571}}
>       }, {
>         "_index" : "locations",
>         "_type" : "location",
>         "_id" : "134",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"name":"TP Ho Chi Minh","address":"TP Ho Chi Minh, Việt Nam","locations":{"lat":16.4674,"lon":107.591}}
>       }, {
>         "_index" : "locations",
>         "_type" : "location",
>         "_id" : "139",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"name":"Chua thien Pagoda","address":"Kim Long, Thừa Thiên Huế, Việt Nam","locations":{"lat":16.4537,"lon":107.545}}
>       }, {
>         "_index" : "locations",
>         "_type" : "location",
>         "_id" : "130",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"name":"Việt Nam","address":"Việt Nam","locations":{"lat":16.9054,"lon":106.576}}
>       }, {
>         "_index" : "locations",
>         "_type" : "location",
>         "_id" : "135",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source":{"name":"Dai Noi Hue","address":"23/8, Thừa Thiên Huế, Việt Nam","locations":{"lat":16.4698,"lon":107.577}}
>       } ]   } }

when i run query with keyword = "viet nam"

```
result :
 _id = [131,132,,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,130]  # => OK working
```

but i when run query with keywork = "thua thien hue"

```
result :
     _id = [132,135,139]  # => Don't working ???, should have been: _id = [132,135,136,137,138,139]
```

Same with keywork = "hue"

```
result :
         _id = [132,135]  # => Don't working ???, should have been: _id = [132,135,136,137,138,139]
```

how search results that contain the above word (add type, or do anything)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error when declaring field `address`. You are declaring `address.address` instead of `address.folded`. In other words, the declaration should be:

```
field :address, type: 'string', analyzer: 'standard' do
  field :folded, type: 'string', analyzer: 'folding'
end
```